# Как отобразить PHP массив в аккуратном в удобно читаемом виде?

Tags: php, массивы

Получаю от API VK ответ и декодирую его из json

```
$result = file_get_contents ($url); 
$b = json_decode($result, true);
print_r ($b);
```

Вывожу через print_r - отображается сплошным текстом. Как отобразить его в удобно читаемом виде? Спасибо.

как пример:

```
Array 
( 
    [0] => 345 
    [1] => mail@mail.ru 
    [2] => http://www.softtime.ru 
    [3] => login 
    [4] => password 
)
```

Comment: Надо открыть для себя **исходный код HTML** , который вызывается по клавише Ctrl-U. И при отладке всегда использовать только его, а не смотреть картинку, которую нарисовал браузер

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Тег `<pre>`

```
$result = file_get_contents ($url); 
$b = json_decode($result, true);
echo '<pre>';
print_r ($b);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: удобнее в одну строку: `echo '<pre>', print_r($b, true), '</pre>';` Её легче закомментировать при необходимости.

Answer (score 0):

Готовая функция для удобоваримого и красивого вывода массивов и данных на скорую руку

```
 function printData($data)
    {
        print_r('<pre><p style="background-color: beige; color: maroon; padding: 10px; margin: 5px; border: 1px maroon solid;">');
        print_r($data);
        print_r('</p></pre>');
    }
```